# FreeWallet eth address is empty

Tags: wallets

I have ETH in my freewallet wallet when I use the app.

But when I access "My wallet address" in etherscan, it is empty and says the coins were sent to another account

Are the coins in FreeWallet's account?

Comment: Are you saying somebody sent the ethers to an address which is not your wallet address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gonna ask freewallet customer support and see how the app handles the fund. But if the app indeed transfer users' fund to their account, that would be highly suspicious.

Account is basically an pair of numbers, the account address is one of them, and the key to the account is the other, whoever holds the key can manage the account and funds deposited within. Wallet is normally the tool to create that pair, then tells the user the address and store the key **locally or offline**.

In EtherScan the user needs to add their address(public key) to the watch list so to have the address appeared in "My Address" section. As long as you have the private key to that address, you should be able to manage it regardless of the type of wallet client.

I suggest to take the following actions:

1. Make sure which account owns the fund for now, it might also be your another account.
2. Try other wallet clients for example: https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet

Hope this helps.

Comment: NP, hope you get it back :)

Comment: Yeah man! Thought we'd lost it. All worked out :)